# Выводить сообщения в консоль при вызове длительной процедуры mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Вызываю длительную хранимую процедуру из mySQL-клиента (heidiSQL).

В процедуре перебираются все записи таблицы циклом по 10тыс записей.

Возможно ли при каждой итерации цикла выводить в консоль клиента какое-либо сообщение?

Answer (score 1):

Можно в цикле процедуры вставить что-то типа:

```
select concat('processed', @i, ' of ', @total);
```